# tcp: many to one, best practices on keeping track of things

Tags: tcp, tcplistener

I have developed a basic tcp client server setup, and its working, but I would like some ideas on what the best practices are for handling / structuring / managing incoming and outgoing requests.

My client app can receive data without requesting it, and it also expects data after purposefully requesting it.

Where I am now, I have basic catches on incoming messages, with headers, to determine what to do with the incoming message.

When I send a request to the server, I temporarily save that request header, enter a waiting loop, and on the condition that my received header = my request header, I resume my code that requested the message in the first place, as to keep my code from continuing on if it has not yet received what it needs from the server (i.e. get client details).

Is this the general way of handling tx/rx that are dependant on each other?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

in your implementation you can only have one outstanding message from client side, its not clear that's what you want to design for. Its done in both ways, it depends on your design. Normally one does it in layered fashion. These are the possible layers:

1. lowest level: you handle connection details
2. next level: some kind of framing protocol: develop a frame based on tcp stream of bytes
3. third level: have some protocol headers which client and server understand. You may have message number in the header so that you can handle multiple outstanding messages and error notification packets.

this is a brief outline of normal practices, one can add lot of values in each layer. thx!